# installing learnyounode with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sudo

The instructions say that I should use

```
sudo npm install -g learnyounode
```

But when I use sudo npm, it says sudo npm command not found

But if I install without sudo using

```
npm install -g learnyounode
```

it complains please run command again as root/administrator.

I do have the sudo password and do have node.js installed. This is a ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you don't have is the paths set up. If it's saying "sudo" not found, then your PATH variable doesn't go through the right directory -- which is usually `/bin`, which would mean you could do almost nothing. But if it's sudoL npm not found, your PATHY in the root account doesn't include npm.

Here's what you do:

1. `$ echo ${PATH}`
2. `$ sudo echo ${PATH}`.

Compare them and fix your path.  Or

1. `$ which npm`

This will give you the full path to the npm executable, something like `/usr/local/bin/npm`.  Then

2. `$ sudo /usr/local/bin/npm`.

Of course substituting what the real path was from step 1.

Comment: My path is correct, both printed out the same thing. When I did a which it uses the same npm. But when I did sudo /fullpathtonode/npm, it worked. Thanks!